# How to do backup restore zookeeper ensemble without exhibitor?

Tags: backup, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, restore

Is there a stable solution to backup and restore zookeeper cluster without exhibitor by manually ?

There is no any documentation or any sample for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use utils like zktreeutil it's quite old but it save the whole tree and you can restore it later.

have a look here :
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/zktreeutil.1.html

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.